# What do the columns of /proc/wakelocks mean?

Tags: android, shell, wakelock, android-wake-lock

After cat /proc/wakelocks i get something like this. But what means number in columns?

```
    ------ KERNEL WAKELOCKS (/proc/wakelocks) ------
name    count   expire_count    wake_count  active_since    total_time  sleep_time  max_time    last_change
"event2-366"    26021   0   0   0   1780516781  0   98555000    2746261947545
"mmc0"  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
"qcril" 467 0   0   0   262658558   1293333 71696667    2745863710879
"rpc_reply" 250 0   0   0   208878752   17641665    21993333    2745857429212
```

- name - this is easy.
- count - how many lock was loced?
- expire_count - no idea. What is this?
- wake_count - same as above. What is this?
- active_since - same as above. What is this?
- total_time - same as above. total time of what?
- sleep_time  - same as above. What is this?
- max_time - same as above. What is this?
- last_change - same as above. What is this?

Answer (score 1):

1. count: indicates how many times the lock was held
2. expire_count: indicates no of times the wakeup sources' timeout has expired. This happens for example when some module has opened a device and not used it for long time. Then upon timeout, wakeup source will expire.
3. active_since: indicates for how long wakeup source is active. The value is in jiffies.
4. total_time: indicates total time in jiffies this wakeup source was held.
5. max_time: indicates maximum time(jiffies) wakeup source was held